# Getting a part of a matrix Inverse for later use

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I was trying to get an element of a matrix, and use in further computation of my program.
Problem was that its not reading the value unless and until I specify it again.

My code is:

```
     G = k1 Log[k1] + (1.1 + k2) Log[k2] + (k1 + k2) Log[k1 + k2]

   (* k1 Log[k1] + (1.1 + k2) Log[k2] + (k1 + k2) Log[k1 + k2]*)

    M1 = FullSimplify[{{D[G, {k1, 2}], D[G, k2, k1]}, {D[G, k1, k2], 
        D[G, {k2, 2}]}}]

    (*{{1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2), 1/(k1 + k2)}, {1/(
      k1 + k2), (-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)}}*)

    M2 = FullSimplify[{D[G, k1], D[G, k2]}]

    (*{2 + Log[k1] + Log[k1 + k2], 2 + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2]}*)

    M3 =
     PowerExpand[Solve[M1.{d1, d2} == -M2, {d1, d2}]]

    (*{{d1 -> -((-1. ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)) (2. + Log[k1] + 
            Log[k1 + k2]) + (2. + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2])/(
         k1 + k2))/(
        1/(k1 + k2)^2 - 
         1. (1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2)) ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)))), 
      d2 -> -(k1 + k2) (2. + Log[k1] + Log[k1 + k2]) + (
        1. (k1 + k2) (1/k1 + 1/(
           k1 + k2)) (-1. ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)) (2. + Log[k1] +
               Log[k1 + k2]) + (2. + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2])/(
           k1 + k2)))/(
        1/(k1 + k2)^2 - 
         1. (1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2)) ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)))}}*)

    G1 = G /. {k1 -> k1 + d1, k2 -> k2 + d2}

    (*(d1 + k1) Log[d1 + k1] + (1.1 + d2 + k2) Log[
       d2 + k2] + (d1 + d2 + k1 + k2) Log[d1 + d2 + k1 + k2]*)
```

If observed the code, its not taking `d1` and `d2`. I tried getting the part this way, `G1=G/.{k1->k1+M3[[1,1]],k2->k2+M3[[1,2]]}`
Still it did not work.
I just wanted to know the way we need to write the syntax , so that if I call `k1->k1+ d1`, it would directly gets summed up with `k1` for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Others will appreciate it if the code can be copied, pasted directly into *Mathematica*, and executed.  The `In`/`Out` tags make that difficult.  If you set the option `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ExportMultipleCellsOptions -> {"IncludeCellLabels" -> False}]`, then they won't be copied from your notebook.  Note using `$FrontEnd` sets it for all sessions.  Use `$FrontEndSession` if you just want to set it for your current session.  Generally people put output inside comments `(*...*)` so that it won't affect execution when pasted.

Comment: `G1 = G /. {k1 -> k1 + d1, k2 -> k2 + d2} /. M3[[1]]`

Comment: Thank you!! Am new to this.. I did not know it though!! I will try to do that!

Comment: You're welcome (if you're responding to me). Thanks for editing the question.  If you put @ in front the user name, like @MichaelE2, the user will get notified of your response to their comment. (The author is always notified, so I didn't have to do that here.)

Comment: @MichaelE2- Oh is this the way!! Ok!! I will do that from here on! Thanks for guiding!

Answer (score 2):

After working a lot I came out with an answer for my own question!!!
Answer is this way(in coded form),

```
     M3 =
     PowerExpand[Solve[M1.{d1, d2} == -M2, {d1, d2}]]

   (* {{d1 -> -((-1. ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)) (2. + Log[k1] + 
            Log[k1 + k2]) + (2. + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2])/(
         k1 + k2))/(
        1/(k1 + k2)^2 - 
         1. (1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2)) ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)))), 
      d2 -> -((0.5 (2.2 k1^2 k2 + 3.3 k1 k2^2 + 2. k1^2 k2^2 + 1.1 k2^3 + 
              4. k1 k2^3 + 2. k2^4 - 1. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1] - 
              1. k1 k2^3 Log[k1] + 2. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k2] + 
              3. k1 k2^3 Log[k2] + k2^4 Log[k2] + 
              k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1 + k2] + 2. k1 k2^3 Log[k1 + k2] + 
              k2^4 Log[k1 + k2]))/(-1.1 k1^2 - 1.65 k1 k2 + k1^2 k2 - 
            0.55 k2^2 + 2. k1 k2^2 + k2^3))}}*)

    G1 = G /. {k1 -> k1 + d1, k2 -> k2 + d2} /. M3

   (* {(1.1 + k2 - (0.5 (2.2 k1^2 k2 + 3.3 k1 k2^2 + 2. k1^2 k2^2 + 

          1.1 k2^3 + 4. k1 k2^3 + 2. k2^4 - 1. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1] - 
          1. k1 k2^3 Log[k1] + 2. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k2] + 
          3. k1 k2^3 Log[k2] + k2^4 Log[k2] + 
          k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1 + k2] + 2. k1 k2^3 Log[k1 + k2] + 
          k2^4 Log[k1 + k2]))/(-1.1 k1^2 - 1.65 k1 k2 + k1^2 k2 - 
        0.55 k2^2 + 2. k1 k2^2 + k2^3)) Log[
    k2 - (0.5 (2.2 k1^2 k2 + 3.3 k1 k2^2 + 2. k1^2 k2^2 + 1.1 k2^3 + 
          4. k1 k2^3 + 2. k2^4 - 1. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1] - 
          1. k1 k2^3 Log[k1] + 2. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k2] + 
          3. k1 k2^3 Log[k2] + k2^4 Log[k2] + 
          k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1 + k2] + 2. k1 k2^3 Log[k1 + k2] + 
          k2^4 Log[k1 + k2]))/(-1.1 k1^2 - 1.65 k1 k2 + k1^2 k2 - 
        0.55 k2^2 + 2. k1 k2^2 + 
        k2^3)] + (k1 - (-1. ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)) (2. + 
         Log[k1] + Log[k1 + k2]) + (
      2. + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2])/(k1 + k2))/(
     1/(k1 + k2)^2 - 
      1. (1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2)) ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)))) Log[
    k1 - (-1. ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)) (2. + Log[k1] + 
         Log[k1 + k2]) + (2. + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2])/(
      k1 + k2))/(
     1/(k1 + k2)^2 - 
      1. (1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2)) ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(
         k1 + k2)))] + (k1 + 
     k2 - (0.5 (2.2 k1^2 k2 + 3.3 k1 k2^2 + 2. k1^2 k2^2 + 1.1 k2^3 + 
          4. k1 k2^3 + 2. k2^4 - 1. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1] - 
          1. k1 k2^3 Log[k1] + 2. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k2] + 
          3. k1 k2^3 Log[k2] + k2^4 Log[k2] + 
          k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1 + k2] + 2. k1 k2^3 Log[k1 + k2] + 
          k2^4 Log[k1 + k2]))/(-1.1 k1^2 - 1.65 k1 k2 + k1^2 k2 - 
        0.55 k2^2 + 2. k1 k2^2 + 
        k2^3) - (-1. ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)) (2. + Log[k1] + 
         Log[k1 + k2]) + (2. + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2])/(
      k1 + k2))/(
     1/(k1 + k2)^2 - 
      1. (1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2)) ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)))) Log[
    k1 + k2 - (0.5 (2.2 k1^2 k2 + 3.3 k1 k2^2 + 2. k1^2 k2^2 + 
          1.1 k2^3 + 4. k1 k2^3 + 2. k2^4 - 1. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1] - 
          1. k1 k2^3 Log[k1] + 2. k1^2 k2^2 Log[k2] + 
          3. k1 k2^3 Log[k2] + k2^4 Log[k2] + 
          k1^2 k2^2 Log[k1 + k2] + 2. k1 k2^3 Log[k1 + k2] + 
          k2^4 Log[k1 + k2]))/(-1.1 k1^2 - 1.65 k1 k2 + k1^2 k2 - 
        0.55 k2^2 + 2. k1 k2^2 + 
        k2^3) - (-1. ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)) (2. + Log[k1] + 
         Log[k1 + k2]) + (2. + 1.1/k2 + Log[k2] + Log[k1 + k2])/(
      k1 + k2))/(
     1/(k1 + k2)^2 - 
      1. (1/k1 + 1/(k1 + k2)) ((-1.1 + k2)/k2^2 + 1/(k1 + k2)))]}*)
```

When it was getting the part out when I call d1, giving "/.M3" i.e, referring to the Parent matrix, gives the value of d1 stored in M3 matrix.

probably many must be knowing this, Still few may be benefitted out of it!

Comment: It's perfectly ok to accept your own answer.  (Click the checkmark below the vote count.)